# PhantomJS screen capture png format

Tags: css, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to export png file. In the downloaded png file, some layout get messed up... although in the browser it looks good. I wonder what does PhantomJS do with the downloaded png file, is it using the same html and css to render it?[image]

Comment: PhantomJS is a headless WebKit, which basically means it's a browser, so it should be using HTML and CSS from the webpage. If you have a webkit browser go to the page and see if looks ok in that browser.

Comment: @IkoTikashi I tested with Chrome and Safari, it looks fine on both browser.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is a headless *browser* and uses the WebKit engine. Depending on your version of PhantomJS, this engine might be either 4 years (v1.x) or one year (v2.x) old. You will have to make adjustments to your CSS to fix this issue on PhantomJS.

What you can also try, is to change the viewportSize. PhantomJS has a size of 400x300. Your page might behave badly for such small viewports. Change to something desktop-like:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 800 };
page.open(url, fn);
```